# How to undo drawstring from gdiplus?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I'm using gdiplus to drawstring on progress bar.

(text = black, progress bar = red)

```
    Graphics* graphics = Graphics::FromHWND(progressbar);
graphics->DrawString(wc, (int) buffer, &myFont, origin, &blackBrush);
DeleteObject(graphics);
```

Could you tell me how to remove this operation after few seconds ?

Comment: You are splattering pixels on the progress bar, this very rarely works out well.  You'll have to sub-class it.  InvalidateRect to repaint.

Answer (score 0):

Once you perform a drawing operation on it, the bitmap backing the graphics context that you have drawn onto has no information about what was there before.

Draw it again (invalidate the rectangle bounding the text) without the text.

Comment: ` WCHAR string[] = L"Sample Text";

 graphics->DrawString(wc, (int) buffer, &myFont, origin, &blackBrush);
 graphics->DrawString(string, 11, &myFont, origin, &blackBrush);` that ? I have two strings on progress bar ;p

Comment: @user2652995 you will have as many string you drew after you cleared the context by invalidating it and painting the background. If you have more strings drawn, they you are not invalidating it correctly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145005(v=vs.85).aspx